# Revive old changes made in foxit reader

Tags: foxit-reader

I was editing a document on foxit reader. While undoing a change I mistakenly undid a lot of previous changes. Without realizing this I continued editing and when I finally realized what had happened, it was too late to just undo changes as I don't want to lose the changes I have done since then.

Can anyone help me to recover them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No; Your changes are lost.

Comment: @Ramhound - I saw there was something like AutoSave file in Foxit PhantomPDF:  https://forums.foxitsoftware.com/forum/portable-document-format-pdf-tools/foxit-phantompdf/169316-autosave-location . Is there any such thing for foxit reader?

Answer (score 0):

The undo buffer in almost all apps is a straight line.

If you go back & make a 'fork' in the road, you lose the other path immediately.

Unless you have an intermediate save you can pick bits out of, you'll have to copy/paste what you currently have into another document, then go back through the undo buffer as far as you can; then paste missing bits from one to the other.

Comment: I have a habit of saving my changes. So how can I access this undo buffer?

Comment: You cannot.  The buffet isn’t unlimited

Comment: The foxit reader manual says that the undo buffer size is 300 by default. The number of changes I have done is less than that. http://cdn01.foxitsoftware.com/pub/foxit/manual/enu/FoxitPDFEditor22_Manual.pdf

Comment: You make an edit 1, then another 2, then a third 3, then you go back to step 1 & do new steps 4 & 5, your old step 2 & 3 is now gone. The buffer is a straight line, 5, 4, 1. Edits 2 & 3 no longer exist. The buffer also exists only so long as the file is open. If you save, close, reopen, it's empty.